# Angularytics issue $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to implement Angularytics but I am getting below error:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider

My index.html includes below scripts:

```
<script src="components/angular/angular.js"></script>
.....
<script src="components/angularytics/src/angularytics.js"></script>
```

And my app.js(route) has below code:

```
var app=angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource','angularytics'])
  .config(function (AngularyticsProvider,$routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

            AngularyticsProvider.setEventHandlers(['Console', 'Google']);

..............................
.................................

  });

app.run(['Angularytics','$rootScope','$location','$routeParams', function(Angularytics,$rootScope,$location,$routeParams) {

    Angularytics.init();
.....................
......................

}]);
```

Please help me in what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add angular-route.js and add ngRoute to the DI libs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="components/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

var app= angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'angularytics'])
```